# nginx serve location with proxy pass and location with error pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, nginx

i have nginx next configuration:

```
http {

...

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  # Only allow these request methods
  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
     return 444;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_cache cache;
    proxy_cache_valid 10m;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_read_timeout 150;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    if (-f /usr/share/nginx/closed) {
        return 503;
    }

    ....

  }
...
}
```

Now i need custom error pages with included css and js, i can do this

```
  error_page  404  /404.html;
  location /404.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
```

And this is works, but i can't serve 404.css and 404.js for an example, i can see only 404.html.

I found this case to serve css and js for errors page:

```
  error_page 500 502 503 @error_page;

  location @error_page {
    root /var/nginx/app/htdocs;
    internal;
  }
```

But it is not work for me for some reason. How i can server custom error pages with css and js included?

Comment: Wouldn't the CSS and JS be served from your regular files? You'll need to handle the paths correctly, since you most likely won't be able to use relative paths..

Answer (score 0):

I think Toby is right.  You'll want to setup a /static/ location (or similar) to serve up your static files, and that should live outside of your root location containing the proxy_pass.  And then your error page should reference the proper urls to the static assets (i.e. /static/404.css).  Your 404.css and 404.js would just be served up like any other asset.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    ...

    location /static/ {
        alias /path/to/htdocs/static/;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {

      ....
    }


}
```